# Subnetting based on networking needs

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I am unable to visualize the solution to the following question

`Your company has obtained the 131.107.168.0 /21 address space from an ISP. You now need to design this address space to accommodate the following network segments.
Segment A: 600 hosts 
Segment B: 300 hosts
Segment C: 150 hosts
Segment D: 75 hosts
Which of the following addresses should you assign the networks?`

The answer is

```
Segment A: 131.107.168.0/22
Segment B: 131.107.172.0/23
Segment C: 131.107.174.0/24
Segment D: 131.107.175.0/25
```

Then, the explanation is

> Segment A needs to support 600 computers and therefore requires a
>   block size of 1024, which describes a /22 network

Ok, I understand subnetting, but the next point I haven't been able to figure out

> Adding 1024 or 4 x 256 to the starting address of 131.107.168.0 brings
>   you to the starting address of Segment B, 131.107.172.0.

I don't understand why you would need to add to the network address. And I cannot even figure out what to google to help me understand this solution. Can you give some starting point. So far, all questions I have seen, and all I have read in is about subnetting, not adding bits to the network address

FYI Here is the entire explanation

> Segment A needs to support 600 computers and therefore requires a
>   block size of 1024, which describes a /22 network. Adding 1024 or 4 x
>   256 to the starting address of 131.107.168.0 brings you to the
>   starting address of Segment B, 131.107.172.0. Segment B needs to
>   support 300 hosts and therefore requires a block size of 512, or a /23
>   network. Adding 512 or 2 x 256 to the starting address of Segment B
>   brings you to the starting address of Segment C, 131.107.174.0.
>   Segment C needs to support 150 hosts, for which a block size of 256 (a
>   /24 network) is needed. Adding 256 to the starting address of Segment
>   C brings you to the starting address of Segment D, 131.107.175.0.
>   Segment D needs to support 75 hosts, for which a block size of 128 is
>   needed. A /25 network is used for this block size.

Comment: when they say 'adding' they aren't talking about binary arithmetic, they way you do with you talk about stealing/giving bits to the network or host ends of the address by masking it. they are simply saying that you need to calculate the end address for segment A and add one (decimal) to get the start address of the next segment, or if you don't want to calculate the end address, you can note that by stealing 2 bits from the network address, that gives you 4 distinct blocks in the 3rd octet (168-171) so you can multiply 4 times the number of hosts in the 4th octet (256).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segment B can't overlap Segment A. Segment A takes up `131.107.168.0`-`131.107.171.255`, so the next starting address that is unallocated is `131.107.172.0`

Comment: Darth Andriod, this is the visual I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main things to understand here:

1. "Segments" must be isolated from each other. Even though /22 can support 1022 hosts (2^10-2), you can't put the 600 hosts of segment A and the 300 hosts of segment B into the same network. If you did segment A hosts could "see" segment B hosts and that's not desired, thus the reason for different segments to begin with.
2. Segment sizes (also called block size) can only be a power of 2. (e.g. you can't have a segment size of 24, but you can have a segment size of 16 or 32.)

Now given those 2 points, Segment A requires 600 hosts, and the smallest power of 2 that can handle that many is 2^10 = 1024. (Remember you must always subtract 2 for the number of hosts available in a segment, to account for the network and broadcast addresses. This means that a single host would require a minimum block size of 4 which allows for 2 hosts. Or, if instead of 600 hosts the question said you needed 1023 hosts, you would have to go to the next power of 2, which is 2048.)

Once we have determined the first segment requires a block size of 1024, we "add" 1024 to the starting network to determine the position of where the next segment must begin. Now look at Darth's Answer and you'll see exactly where the next network segment should begin.